# Extracting sulphur from hot springs with medieval technology?

Tags: elements, chemistry-in-fiction

For the sake of a dungeons and dragons game. Could sulphur be deposited on/extracted from hot springs water through evaporation or other proess?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sulfur does naturally occur around [hot springs and volcanos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sulfur#Natural_occurrence). It would be very reasonable to assume that a hot spring could have natural deposits of sulfur near it that could be collected without any special effort.

Answer (score 0):

Time to dig into the ancient alchemical texts or modern "witchy" stuff. The ancient knowledge of substances and plants would be lost were in not for herbal healers and Wiccans.
Sublimation of Sulfur to get the "flowers of sulfur"
I would love to try this, but my income levels limit my "craft" to making tea!
https://distillatio.wordpress.com/2013/02/13/sublimation-of-sulphur-fantastic-photos/